# TFlite: `ValueError: Mmap of '118' failed`

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I'm using inside of an init():

```
from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

self.interpreter = Interpreter(self.selectedLayer)
```

But I'm getting `ValueError: Mmap of '118' failed.`

I have an array of avaliable layers, which are then initialised each time a new test is run.

```
def __init__(self, layer):
availableLayers= {
            "apps":'/home/pi/Desktop/python/NNs/tflite/appModel'
            # ...more layers like this
}
self.layerChosen = layer
self.saveDirectory = "/home/pi/Desktop/"
self.selectedLayer = availableLayers[layer]+"/model.tflite"
self.label = self.loadLabels(availableLayers[layer]+"/labels.txt")
self.interpreter = Interpreter(self.selectedLayer)
# This is where the Mmap error is occuring

self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()
self.input_details = self.interpreter.get_input_details()
self.output_details = self.interpreter.get_output_details()
self.floating_model = self.input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32
self.height = self.input_details[0]['shape'][1]
self.width = self.input_details[0]['shape'][2]
```

This error occurs after a few tests have already run. The `init()` is repeated on each new test.

Baring this in mind, I'm thinking it could be a memory issue. Is there a way I can increase memory to `Interpretor`?